# Delete selected items in a GridView

Tags: c#, windows-8

```
IList<object> itemsSelected = MyGrid.SelectedItems;

foreach (object itemSelected in itemsSelected)
{
   MyGrid.SelectedItems.Remove(itemSelected);
}
```

I try remove selected items from a GridView but not all selected items are removed.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Where is this piece of code declared within the page lifecycle? `OnLoad`, `OnInit`...?

Comment: It is the action of a button the app bar, remove selected items.

Comment: [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) doesn't seem to have a `SelectedItems` property. Is `SelectedItems` an extension?

Comment: Activating the multiSelection property...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object[] itemsSelected = MyGrid.SelectedItems.ToArray<object>();
        foreach (object item in itemsSelected)
        {
            MyGrid.Items.Remove(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem as well. I wrote something like this but it didn't delete all items too, just some of them :

```
foreach(var item in MyGridView.SelectedItems)
{
     MyGridView.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

But write this which will delete all your selected items for sure :

```
while (YourGridView.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
{
    YourGridView.Items.Remove(YouGridView.SelectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there isn't exception, when you use foreach with SelectedItems? When you remove item, SelectedItems array is modified and foreach throws an exception. (Though I've tried on ListBox control). Try to use for-operator and remove items from last to first by index.

Comment: There isn't exception. Some items are deleted.. but others stay in selected yet.

Comment: it's like I need to implement an Iterator used in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers in the comments, I assume you are working on a C# winforms application.

Is it possible that what you are actualy using is a `ListBox` and **not** a `GridView`?

If that is so, you should use the [`ClearSelected()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.clearselected.aspx) method which unselects all items in the `ListBox`.